# What is the cumulative defensive effect of stacking the following feats?

Tags: dnd-4e

I am looking for the cumulative defensive value when applying the following feats & effects.  This example assumes I have the following feats and am opting to spend an extra power point when casting an at-will.

Predictive Defense (PHB3)
Benefit: Whenever you hit an enemy with a psionic at-will attack power that is unaugmented, you gain a +2 bonus to all defences against melee attacks until the end of your next turn.

Prescient Dodge[Augment] (Psionic Power)
Benefit: Whenever you hit an enemy with an unaugmented attack power, you can spend 1 power point to gain a +2 power bonus to all defences until the start of your next turn.

Mark of Warding[Dragonmark] (Eberron Player's Guide)
Benefit: Whenever one of your powers grants a bonus to a defence, increase that bonus by 1.

What are my defences versus melee & range?  Things I'm considering in this is will using prescient dodge void predictive defence or would they both apply as prescient dodge requires an unaugmented attack power to use and you spend the point after you hit? Lastly, will Mark of Warding up the defence of both prescient dodge & predictive defence should they stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Spending a power point to activate a feat is not the same as augmenting a power.

When you use Prescient Dodge, the at-will which triggers it is still un-augmented because you spent the power point to active a feat. This means activating Prescient Dodge does not remove the bonus granted by Predictive Defense.

### The two bonuses stack because they are of different types.

Predictive Defense gives you an untyped bonus, which should stack with everything except itself. Prescient Dodge's bonus is of the "power" type, making it stack with all bonuses that are not also power-type bonuses.

### But Mark of Warding does not increase bonuses granted by sources other than powers.

Mark of Warding only activates "whenever one of your powers grants a bonus to a defence" and neither of the bonuses from Predictive Defense and Prescient Dodge come from powers; they come from feats. This is slightly confusing because Prescient Dodge grants a bonus of the "power" type, but that's the KIND of bonus it is, and Mark of Warding is only concerned about where the bonus *comes from*. Since it comes from a feat and not a power, Mark of Warding does not enhance it.

So you get a +2 power bonus to all defenses, with an additional +2 untyped bonus (total of +4 to defenses) against melee attacks. Please note that they have different durations; the power bonus lasts until the *start* of your next turn and the untyped bonus lasts until the *end* of your next turn.

Comment: Also spending the power point to activate Prescient Dodge is kind of a waste. Your Power Points should be used for something better than +2 vs ranged attacks.